# Center All Elements to a Certain Width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get everything to center and to about 80% of the page. Everything seems fine, except for my two main divs extend over my banner and nav bar by about 1px, even though they are set to 80%.

Here is the CSS: https://pastebin.com/HM7PLqX0

```css
body {
  background: url('bg.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
}

.banner {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url('bg.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  line-height: 120px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
  width: 80%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.about {
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.stats {
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='logo'>
  The Realm MC
</div>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class='active'><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     Home</a>
  <a href="#play"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     Play</a>
  <a href="/forum"><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     Forums</a>
  <a href="#donate" style="float: right; margin-right: 30px;"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     Donate</a>
</div>

<div class='banner'>
  There are 7 out of 10 players online!
</div>
<br />


<div id='wrapper' style='text-align:center;'>
  <div class='about'>
    Lorem ipsum<br /> dolor sit amet
  </div>

  <div class='stats'>
    Lorem ipsum<br /> dolor sit amet
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mention any with for **wrapper** div, therefore it is assigned 100% of the width available and div inside it will take width accordingly.

Try reducing the width of **about** div to 59% as shown below, this will make both divs lie inside 80% of width scope :

```
.about {
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  width: 59%;
  height: 300px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

Here is the fiddle for that : https://jsfiddle.net/rp1shr4t/

or you can set width of **wrapper** div as you have done **topnav** div and then set width of inner divs accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems working fine.

```css
body{
  background: url('bg.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
}
 
.banner {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url('bg.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  line-height: 120px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
  width: 80%;
  height:120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
 
 
.about {
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
.stats {
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
 
.logo {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
 
}
 
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='logo'>The Realm MC</div>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class='active'><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>
  <a href="#play"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>Play</a>
  <a href="/forum"><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Forums</a>
  <a href="#donate" style="float: right; margin-right: 30px;"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Donate</a>
</div>
<div class='banner'>
    There are <?php echo $ServerStatus['numplayers'] . " out of " . $ServerStatus['maxplayers'] . " players online!"; ?>
</div>
<br/>
<div id='wrapper' style='text-align:center;'>    
  <div class='about'> 
    Lorem ipsum<br />        
    dolor sit amet    
  </div>    

  <div class='stats'>   
    Lorem ipsum<br />      
    dolor sit amet    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You must assign a `width:80%` for wrapper.
>
> use of `float` property instead of `display:inline-block`.

**So,Change Like this :**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 80%;/*/<-------------------/*/
    margin: 0 auto;/*/<-------------------/*/
    box-sizing: border-box;/*/<-------------------/*/
}

.about {
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.8;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;/*/<-------------------/*/
  height: 300px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  float: left;/*/<-------------------/*/
  /*/-------Remove display:inline-block-----------/*/
}

.stats {
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.8;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  width: 29%;/*/<---------1% for margin-left ----------/*/
  height: 300px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  float: right;/*/<-------------------/*/
   /*/-------Remove display:inline-block-----------/*/
}
```

**This is** [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/am6azs4k/)